# Woocommerce get list of order statuses list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a list of order statuses

```
array(7) { ["wc-pending"]=> string(15) "Pending Payment" ["wc-processing"]=> string(10) "Processing" ["wc-on-hold"]=> string(7) "On Hold" ["wc-completed"]=> string(9) "Completed" ["wc-cancelled"]=> string(9) "Cancelled" ["wc-refunded"]=> string(8) "Refunded" ["wc-failed"]=> string(6) "Failed" }
```

This is what I get in new woocommerce version 2.3.13.

I want older version woocoomerce 2.0 to order statuses list like this, how can I get all list?

Anyone tell me some ideas

Comment: Why are you still using WooCommerce 2.0? 2.4 is coming out soon. You really should stay updated... especially with e-commerce software.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59869889

Answer (score 1):

In WooCommerce 2.0, statuses were associated with orders via a taxonomy called shop_order_status

```
$statuses = get_terms('shop_order_status');
```

or even

```
$my_status_orders = get_term_by('slug', 'my_status', 'shop_order_status');
```

Comment: buddy i am var_dump two variable $statuses and $my_status_orders  but I'm not get any order statuses list   .

Comment: try to set `<taxonomy translate="0">shop_order_status</taxonomy>` in `wpml-config.xml`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59869889

Comment: This no longer works - WC is now in version 8.x and the answer is in linked answer of @EmptyBrain above.