# How to get slugs and names of all order statuses in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, orders

I would like to get all slugs and names of all the WooCommerce order statuses.
I tried the answers from the following thread: [Woocommerce get list of order statuses list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672074/woocommerce-get-list-of-order-statuses-list) but with no success.

I use latest woocommerce version. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will use the dedicated function [`wc_get_order_statuses()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-order-functions.php#L86-L104), from WC_Order functions, which give you by default the following array:

```
$order_statuses = array(
    'wc-pending'    => _x( 'Pending payment', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-processing' => _x( 'Processing', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-on-hold'    => _x( 'On hold', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-completed'  => _x( 'Completed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-cancelled'  => _x( 'Cancelled', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-refunded'   => _x( 'Refunded', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-failed'     => _x( 'Failed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
);
```

> All **custom additional order statuses will be included too** as the filter hook `wc_order_statuses` is applied inside this function.

Answer (score -1):

Add below snippet to functions.php and call woocommerce_get_order_statuses() where you want to use.

```
function woocommerce_get_order_statuses() {
      $order_statuses = get_terms( 'shop_order_status', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );
      $statuses = array();
      foreach ( $order_statuses as $status ) {
        $statuses[ $status->slug ] = $status->name;
      }
      return $statuses;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

*wc_get_order_statuses()* will provide only default WooCommerce statuses but to get all order statuses you may use the following function **woocommerce_get_all_order_statuses()**

```
function woocommerce_get_all_order_statuses() {
  $order_statuses = get_posts( array('post_type'=>'wc_order_status', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'numberposts'=>-1) );
 
  $statuses = array();
  foreach ( $order_statuses as $status ) {
    $statuses[ $status->post_name ] = $status->post_title;
  }

  return $statuses;
}
```