# Block certain WooCommerce webhooks from firing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

In the application I am running, we need to stop certain orders from getting sent to inFlow inventory management.

I want to stop orders with the status of Estimate from making it all the way through the process.

From what I've read, hooking into `woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver` and returning `$should_delever == false` should stop the webhook from firing, but I am unable to get it to.

```
function should_deliver_order_creation($should_deliver, $wc_webhook, $arg) {
    $order = wc_get_order($arg);
    $order->get_status();
    if(str_contains($wc_webhook->get_name(), 'inFlow') && $order->get_status() == 'estimate') {
        $should_deliver = false;
    }
    return $should_deliver;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver', 'should_deliver_order_creation', 9, 3);
```

Orders with a status of 'estimate' are still going through

Are there any other hooks I should try to get into to to make the order stop going through?

Comment: Have you already tried `$should_deliver = false; return $should_deliver;` without all the other conditions, to see if it has any effect? that way you can determine if you're using the right hook

Comment: That does not seem to have any effect. Added that, orders still going through. I have access to the webhook and related methods. Could one of them be used to cancel sending?

Answer (score 1):

`woocommerce_webhook_should_deliver` is the correct and I think only way to accomplish this.

Here are a few steps that could validate your code for you:

1. You should check if your code is able to get the order object correctly, you can do a debug and die to see if your `$arg` and order objects are correct
2. `$order->get_status();` this line does nothing
3. Instead of comparing the name of the webhook I would recommend checking on the [delivery url](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Webhook.html#method_get_delivery_url), because anybody could change the name of the hook, while the url has to be a target to the inFlow infrastructure
4. Check the order status is correct, it seems to be a non default one, see [those defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59869889/13765033) for their names, just make sure yours is correct

---

I was able to use the hook for a slightly different purpose, but also to stop delivering some webhooks, and get it working, perhaps [this code](https://github.com/devidw/no-wc-make-loop/blob/591a4bae23b4cecc7ac8256ea73f11f2b09eb9fb/no-wc-make-loop.php) helps you as well.

Answer (score 1):

When the webhook is fired through an `order.created` trigger, the order object is empty, so getting it's status with `$order->get_status()` results in an empty string. I'm having the same issue when trying to fetch the order items using `$order->get_items()` to determine if the webhook should be delivered or not.

When the webhook is fired through an `order.updated` trigger, the order objects is fully populated and contains the correct status and order items.

In my situation, I am able to get the order items from the cart object instead of the order object: `wc()->cart->get_cart()`, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the order status of an order that hasn't been fully stored yet.